# Is there a way to use the browsable API for Django Rest Framework with Authtoken

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication

How can I use the Django Rest Framework browsable API for a particular user by authenticating via authtoken (instead of username/pwd)? The same way I would do for POSTMAN in Chrome

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check [modheader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en). It allows you to set headers for your request. You can set the token authtoken there where "Name" would be "Authorization" and "Value" would be "Token <your_token>"

Comment: This breaks the theme for me, as well as some functionality. Do you experience the same?

Comment: Works flawlessly for me, tx

Comment: Caution: I just spent hours thinking our implementation was broken because I kept getting "Unable to decode signature" because the plugin was changing the bearer on me...